# How to execute a python module (python -m json.tool) programatically?

Tags: python

I want to execute json.tool in my code and return the output (because of some weirdness json.dumps doesn't work for me. However, dumping the json to a file and running it through `python -m json.tool` gives me what I want).

How can I execute json.tool within my code programatically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use the python -m mymod syntax from within the python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396373/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-python-m-mymod-syntax-from-within-the-python-interpre)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`json.tool` does nothing more than:

```
with infile:
    obj = json.load(infile)
with outfile:
    json.dump(obj, outfile, sort_keys=True,
              indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

where `infile` and `outfile` default to `stdin` and `stdout` respectively.

If you have an object already, you can get the same effect with:

```
import json, sys

json.dump(obj, sys.stdout, sort_keys=True,
          indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

or

```
print json.dumps(obj, sort_keys=True,
                 indent=4, separators=(',', ': '))
```

Comment: [Changed in Python 3.5](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#module-json.tool): The default behavior for the command line interface is that output is now in the same order as the input. The CLI can use the --sort-keys option to sort the output of dictionaries alphabetically by key.