# Is there a way to use the python -m mymod syntax from within the python interpreter?

Tags: python

Many packages like unittest have an easy to use command line interface, e.g. the test discovery feature in unittest: https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#test-discovery

However, to achieve the same from within python, it is sometimes necessary to dig in much deeper in the documentation. In the example above, the python code required to achieve the same is much harder to figure out compared to the command line command.

Therefore, I want to know: Is there a consistent way to translate `python -m mymod args` to something, that can be used within the python interpreter?

Edit: I'm asking for a reasonable strategy what to do in a situation, where I know the python -m command but nothing more. Is this knowledge completely useless when I am forced to use the python interpreter?

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Why would it be a pain? The implementation is [specifically wrapped up in a convenient module for you to use](https://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html).

Comment: If you control the module you're trying to run, it's simple enough to just make a `main` function, but if you're dealing with someone else's code, that's not always possible.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: My questions is about third party modules, like unittest, where it is extreamly easy to find the required `python -m commands` (have a look at the test discovery chapter in the unittest help) but much harder to find the corresponding python code.

Comment: @user2357112: duh, I completely forgot about `runpy`.

Comment: @user2357112: the [`runpy.py` source code](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/runpy.py) takes care of the pain. Note the use of a context manager to replace and restore specific `sys.modules` and `sys.argv` values...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`runpy.run_module` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/runpy.html#runpy.run_module):

```
import runpy
import sys

sys.argv[1:] = ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3']
runpy.run_module('module.name', run_name='__main__', alter_sys=True)
```

This executes `module.name` as if you typed:

```
python -m module.name arg1 arg2 arg3
```