# How to "run with -m" directly in python code instead of a command like "python -m ..."?

Tags: python

How to run with "-m some-module" directly in python code?

Recently I learned that running a command like below can run some torch.distributed python modules:

"python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=2
 SOME_TRAINING_SCRIPT.py"

========

If I want to achieve running SOME_TRAINING_SCRIPT.py by torch.distributed.launch by just executing script **python SOME_TRAINING_SCRIPT.py** (instead of **python -m torch.distributed.launch
   --nproc_per_node=2 SOME_TRAINING_SCRIPT.py**), what things should be added to SOME_TRAINING_SCRIPT.py to achieve this?

The python file is like below:

```
import torch, os
import torch.nn as nn
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
from torch.utils.data.distributed import DistributedSampler
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = "1,2"
os.environ['MASTER_ADDR'] = '127.0.0.1'
os.environ['MASTER_PORT'] = '29500'

torch.distributed.init_process_group(backend="gloo")

input_size = 5
output_size = 2
batch_size = 30
data_size = 90

local_rank = torch.distributed.get_rank()
torch.cuda.set_device(local_rank)
device = torch.device("cuda", local_rank)

print("local_rank = ", local_rank)

class RandomDataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self, size, length):
        self.len = length
        self.data = torch.randn(length, size).to('cuda')

    def __getitem__(self, index):
        return self.data[index]

    def __len__(self):
        return self.len


dataset = RandomDataset(input_size, data_size)
rand_loader = DataLoader(dataset=dataset,
                         batch_size=batch_size,
                         sampler=DistributedSampler(dataset))

class Model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, output_size):
        super(Model, self).__init__()
        self.fc = nn.Linear(input_size, output_size)

    def forward(self, input):
        output = self.fc(input)
        print("  In Model: input size", input.size(),
              "output size", output.size())
        return output


model = Model(input_size, output_size)
model.to(device)

if torch.cuda.device_count() > 1:
    print("Let's use", torch.cuda.device_count(), "GPUs!")
    model = torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel(model,
                                                      device_ids=[local_rank],
                                                      output_device=local_rank)

for data in rand_loader:
    if torch.cuda.is_available():
        input_var = data
    else:
        input_var = data
    output = model(input_var)
    print("Outside: input size", input_var.size(), "output_size", output.size())
```

Comment: I’d start by looking at the source code of `torch.distributed.launch`. It’s likely just some wrapper around importing some classes and functions which it calls in the end. You can import and call the same things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to use the python -m mymod syntax from within the python interpreter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39396373/is-there-a-way-to-use-the-python-m-mymod-syntax-from-within-the-python-interpre)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to just shorten the running command for your training script, you can simply achieve this using a `bash` scripts (Mac/Unix).

**Bash Script Example**

Create a file called `run_distributed_training.sh` with content:

```
#!/bin/sh
python -m torch.distributed.launch --nproc_per_node=2 SOME_TRAINING_SCRIPT.py
```

Then you'll need to set permissions to execute this:

```sh
chmod +x run_distributed_training.sh
```

Finnaly, you can execute like this:

```sh
./run_distributed_training.sh
```

You can achieve the same for Windows using `.bat` scripts.

Explained here: [Creating a BAT file for python script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4571244/creating-a-bat-file-for-python-script)